# Activity being created twice?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a canvas, where I start a new activity if a button is pressed. Here is the code for that:

```
            if((x>(canvas.getWidth()/2)-(playFixed.getWidth()/2)&&(x<(canvas.getWidth()/2)-(playFixed.getWidth()/2) + playFixed.getWidth()))
                    && ((y > 4*(canvas.getHeight()/9))&& (y<100+(8*(canvas.getHeight()/17)+playFixed.getHeight())))){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WhichGameActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
            }
```

And then in the other activity, I have a back button that should finish the activity like this:

```
    Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button_which_game);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Yet I have to press it twice in order for my app to go back to the original activity. Any ideas as to why this is and what a fix would be?

Comment: What kind of callback does your posted `if` condition live in, and what other code is there? It might fire twice, i.e. on a touch down and touch up event.

Comment: I put it in the canvas run() method. Should I move it to touch up?

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint (or log statement for that matter) to double check whether the inside of the `if` condition is firing twice?